# Whether the free space of JVM can be used by other applications

Tags: java, jvm

Suppose the maximum size of a JVM heap is 2GB (-Xmx2048m -Xms100m), we find that the peak *used* usage of this heap is 1GB and the peak *committed* usage is 1.2GB after it finishes. So, my question is whether the free space (2GB - 1.2GB) can be consumed by other applications while the JVM is running.

I think the free space cannot be used by others but I'm not sure currently: The operating system reserves 2GB free space before the JVM runs. The reserved space may not be consumed by other applications though the JVM cannot use it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JVM checks whether OS has enough address space for -Xmx, but OS won't actually allocate the memory until that much is requested by JVM. JVM will only reserve -Xms memory but can extend upto -Xmx provided that much memory is available.

Comment: For my own curiosity: Are you positive it checks for -Xmx contiguous space? That seems like an unreliable test as it could change during run time (and also unnecessary as some operating systems can shuffle other pages around to make space for a large contiguous allocation on request).

Comment: @JasonC i have put it as i remember reading somewhere. I am still searching for the reference and will update the answer if required. So hold on for some time :-)

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()` will return the current size of the heap, which will not exceed the maximum size specified on the command line.

That is approximately the amount of memory assigned to the JVM (not including non-heap JVM memory) by the operating system. Other memory is free for use by other applications.

Of course that is grossly oversimplified -- total system memory is total physical memory + total available swap, with other complications (e.g. Linux makes promises of memory to processes but doesn't actually commit it to that process unless it is touched, also simplified). In any case though, the short answer is: Yes, you specify a *maximum* size on the command line, but the *current* size is what is allocated to the JVM; the rest is available for other applications.

Answer (score 0):

The memory seen by Java process is virtual memory. The operating system doesn't need to really reserved 2GB free physical memory for Java process.